# How to define the default values for a column when creating tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, default-value

What is the SQL to define `DEFAULT` values in MySQL?

In the code below what needs to be added / changed to give IsObsolete a default value of `N`?

```
CREATE TABLE Team
(
    TeamId              CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    DateCreated          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    IsObsolete           CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT N,
    UpdateTime           TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Super noob here, why CHAR(1) and not boolean?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
IsObsolete           CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'
```

Comment: hehe, thanks...overlooked something so simple.  Appreciate the help

Comment: Happens :D. I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to put quotes around it:

```
CREATE TABLE Team
(
    TeamId              CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    DateCreated          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    IsObsolete           CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    UpdateTime           TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: +1 looks like your answer came in a few seconds later.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If your are changing your structure via phpMyAdmin, you should just type in the char (e.g N) as opposed to 'N'